# Mapping query response to typed interface in pg-promise

Tags: pg-promise

I have started using `pg-promise`. I wanted to check if `pg-promise` map the response to a typed interface object ?

e.g.

I have a query like below

```
export interface User {
  username: string;
  status: string;
}

const result = await db.oneOrNone<User>("select * FROM users where username = $1", "something");
```

The result has all the columns and not just interface fields. Am I missing something or is it not in scope of the library

I am not using the repository as suggested in the demo, instead directly trying to query. Will that make any impact?

Answer (score 0):

> The result has all the columns and not just interface fields. Am I missing something or is it not in scope of the library.

Type casting that you use has nothing to do with data processing.

To affect the data retrieved, you should specify the columns:

```js
const result = await db.oneOrNone<User>("SELECT username, status FROM users...
```